# SNS/SQS vs Kinesis for audit log/event data collection

Tags: events, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-kinesis

We generally use SNS/SQS for inter-service communication. Now, We need to have a microservice - call it audit or events. It basically keeps track of user activity with different parts of the system. To me, it looks like events streaming in from multiple microservices to our new "events" service. I generally read "Kinesis is better suited for -Log and event data collection as a use case of Kinses instead of SNS/SQS".

The question is why. What do I not get from SNS/SQS in this case that I should consider Kinses for the event and log data collection instead of the SNS/SQS workflow?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Find the table having selection criteria for various AWS Services for Streaming and messsaging strong textenter image description here]
Find the table having selection criteria for various AWS Services for Streaming and messaging